# Failed to send parameter to PHP POST parameter android

Tags: php, android, post, parameters, json

I am currently using android volley and trying to select the product detail by sending the productID to get the detail data of the product.

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try {
        params.put("ProductID", intent.getStringExtra("productID"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest detailReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            txtNama.setText(intent.getStringExtra("nama"));
            txtManufacturer.setText(intent.getStringExtra("namaVendor"));
            txtHarga.setText("Rp. " + intent.getStringExtra("harga"));
            try {
                if(!response.getString("Foto1").equals(""))
                fotoUrl.add(response.getString("Foto1"));
                if(!response.getString("Foto2").equals(""))
                fotoUrl.add(response.getString("Foto2"));
                if(!response.getString("Foto3").equals(""))
                fotoUrl.add(response.getString("Foto3"));
                if(!response.getString("Foto4").equals(""))
                fotoUrl.add(response.getString("Foto4"));
                if(!response.getString("Foto5").equals(""))
                fotoUrl.add(response.getString("Foto5"));
                txtDesc.setText(response.getString("Deskripsi"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageFragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(ProductActivity.this, "Error occurred! Please check your internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(detailReq);
```

But the onErrorResponse method always gets called. This is my php code:

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

$query = "SELECT Foto1, Foto2, Foto3, Foto4, Foto5, Deskripsi 
           FROM `product` WHERE `ProductID` = '". $_POST['ProductID']."'";

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    echo json_encode($row);
}

?>
```

But when i change the value of $_POST['ProductID'] into for example '0001', the php works just fine. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
 void MakePostRequest() {
            StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndPoints.BASE_URL_ADS,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                value1= jsonResponse.getString("Your ID1");
                                value2= jsonResponse.getString("Your ID2");

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                banner_id = null;
                                full_id = null;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            error.printStackTrace();
                            value1= null;
                            value2= null;
                        }
                    }
            ) {
           // here is params will add to your url using post method
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("app", getString(R.string.app_name));
                    //params.put("2ndParamName","valueoF2ndParam");
                    return params;
                }
            };
            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
        }
```

This post request is using this compile `com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19` volley version.

i am just adding app name as parameter.you can add more params.

Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

You'd better check the question separately for Server and Android, as you mentioned sometimes Server works good.

### Server check

1. You can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com),to test whether Server is ok, or on what conditions, Server is bad. Especially check your Server's response is standard Json format. If you want do it easier, temporarily change `$_POST` to `$_GET`, and install Chrome [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=zh-CN&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher). Then test it by your Chrome.
2. Check `ProductID` format in your databases. If it is `text`, you'd better first `$product_id = $_POST['ProductID']`, and then use `"$product_id"`

### Android check

1. I strongly suggest use `StringRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest`, manually convert `String` to `JSONObject`. If response string is not JSONObject, then you can print it and find exception.
2. use below code to create JSONObject params:

   `Map<String, Object> paramsMap = new HashMap<>();
           paramsMap.put("ProductID", 3);
           JSONObject params = new JSONObject(paramsMap);`

Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

to debug more, you can add at the top of the php code the following 
   var_dump($_POST); die();

and then see in the android what are the values printed, if you get nothing it means the android didn't send the request correctly.

Comment: it said org.json.JSONException: Value array(0) of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: so this mean that the request didn't make to the PHP, are you sure you are using the right format for volley ?

Comment: i think the volley system's jsonobjectrequest is a little buggy, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442977/volley-jsonobjectrequest-post-parameters-no-longer-work