# Why null value in my HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, android-volley

Why is `phonenumber` in my `HashMap` giving me a null value? The idea is that I loop through all contacts on my phone. In my `try - catch` statement, which is working fine, I see all my contacts in logcat with :

```
System.out.println("JSON: " + phonenumber);
```

But with my code `System.out.println("contact is : " + phonenumber);` later on in the Hashmap I get in logcat :

```
contact is : null
```

I want to post all the phone numbers to a MySql database, can you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // this is the php file we are contacting with Volley
    private static final String CHECKPHONENUMBER_URL = "http://www.sitetocheckwithVolley.com/filetocheckwithVolley.php";

    //we are posting phoneNo, which in PHP is phonenumber
    public static final String KEY_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";

    //alContacts is a list of all the phone numbers
    public static final ArrayList<String> alContacts = new ArrayList<String>();

    Button buttonCheck;
    TextView textView;

    String phonenumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);



        //get the names and phone numbers of all contacts in phone book
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {


                String id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        alContacts.add(phoneNo);
                        // break;
                    }
                    pCur.close();

                }
            }
        }

        buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                CheckifUserisContact();
            }
        });

    }



    private void CheckifUserisContact() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CHECKPHONENUMBER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObjectContact = new JSONObject();
                            //put all phone contacts into jsonObjectContact
                            for (int i = 0; i < alContacts.size(); i++)
                            {
                         // jsonObjectContact will be of the form {"phone_number":"123456789"}
                                jsonObjectContact.put("phone_number", alContacts.get(i));

                                //make a new string phonenumber for each JSON contact
                                phonenumber = jsonObjectContact.getString("phone_number");
                                textView.append(phonenumber + " \n");

                                System.out.println("JSON: " + phonenumber);
                            }

                        } catch (final JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("FAILED", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        } }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }) {

         @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
             //The KEY, KEY_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber" . In PHP we will have $_POST["phonenumber"]
             //The VALUE, phonenumber, will be of the form "12345678"
                params.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER,phonenumber);
                System.out.println("contact is : " + phonenumber);
                return params;


        }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

Comment: Hashmap.get returns null when the key is doesn't exist. Or you explicitly put null object

Comment: If you're trying to POST JSON, you wouldn't you StringRequest

Comment: The key is KEY_PHONENUMBER.

Comment: That's great, but you're printing a null string. The same null string is in the Hashmap. You can even print before the StringRequest. The variable will be null there too

Comment: I'm honesty not sure why you're trying to POST a single string instead of the Arraylist

Comment: I'm trying to post all numbers as JSON objects - all the phone contacts - that is, as per the code in my 'try statement' . But starting by learning to do just a single string first. If you know an easy way how to modify my code so it does all the contacts I'd be delighted to hear it.

Comment: In fact, I'm quite sure you can POST JSON using StringRequest :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442977/volley-jsonobjectrequest-post-parameters-no-longer-work

Comment: Sure, you can, but it's a use case that JSONArrayRequest was made for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get in logcat :
>
> ```
>   contact is : null
> ```

Because it's never assigned between onCreate and the getParams() methods

```
String phonenumber;  // null until onResponse
```

It'll also continue to be null while `alContacts.isEmpty()` according to the logic of the code

> //The VALUE, phonenumber, will be of the form "12345678"

Okay, then set it to that instead of not setting it at all

You seem to be using a `String phoneNo`... Is that what you want instead? Then don't make a secondary String variable and instead assign the field. However, then you only are posting the last string of the contacts, not the whole list

---

Note, this is how to correctly  iterate a Cursor

```
   if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
```

Or simply

```
for (cur.moveToFirst(); cur.moveToNext(); ) {
```

---

And, as pointed out, you're collecting a list, but only putting in one element into the parameters. Did you want to post a JSONArray?

Comment: Thanks for the Cursor iteration tip. What's wrong with 'cur.getCount()>0' ? I'm guessing it's because if the user has no contacts it causes problems.

Comment: I was under the impression that it advances the cursor so there's nothing to iterate

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cricket_007 answer above, I modified my code like so :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // this is the php file we are contacting with Volley
    private static final String CHECKPHONENUMBER_URL = "http://www.thesitetocheck.com/thefiletocheck.php";

    //we are posting phoneNo, which in PHP is phonenumber
    public static final String KEY_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";

    //alContacts is a list of all the phone numbers
    public static final ArrayList<String> alContacts = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSONObject jsonObjectContact = new JSONObject();

    Button buttonCheck;
    TextView textView;
    String phoneNo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);



        //get the names and phone numbers of all contacts in phone book
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {


                String id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        alContacts.add(phoneNo);
                        // break;
                    }
                    pCur.close();

                }
            }
        }

        buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try {


                    //put all phone contacts into jsonObjectContact
                    for (int i = 0; i < alContacts.size(); i++)
                    {
                        // jsonObjectContact will be of the form {"phone_number":"123456789"}
                        jsonObjectContact.put("phone_number", alContacts.get(i));

                        textView.append(jsonObjectContact + " \n");

                        System.out.println("JSON: " + jsonObjectContact);
                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("FAILED", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                CheckifUserisContact();
            }
        });

    }



    private void CheckifUserisContact() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CHECKPHONENUMBER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }) {

         @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
             //The KEY, KEY_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber" . In PHP we will have $_POST["phonenumber"]
             //The VALUE, phonenumber, will be of the form "12345678"
                params.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER,jsonObjectContact.toString());
                System.out.println("contact is : " + jsonObjectContact);
                return params;


        }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
}
```

Comment: You're still only putting one string, not "all" like your comment says since JSON can't have duplicate keys. Try posting a JSONArray instead

Comment: In my'for loop' for textView.append and System.out.println for jsonObjectContact I get all the entries in my phone in the format : {phone_number : 12345678} , {phone_number : 23456789}, etc.....all JSON Objects. Are you saying it is not possible to post these to MySQL db the way I am doing it ?

Comment: I'm sure you could do that, but using a TextView (or any UI component) as a temporary "container" for your data usually is the wrong idea. Because you're still sending a comma delimited string to PHP, not a valid JSON object